# Delete documents from different collections in MongoDB from NodeJS to maintain database consistency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these collections: articles, favorites, and comments. I want to delete an article and with it, delete its comments and favorites.

My code:

```
        //delete comments
        await this.commentsService.deleteArticleComments(articleId);

        //delete favorites
        await this.favoritesService.deleteArticleFavorites(articleId);

        //delete article
        await this.articlesService.deleteArticle(articleId);
```

Each one calls to a method in service that does the deletion with Mongoose:

```
async deleteArticleComments(articleId: string){
    return await this.commentModel.deleteMany({articleId}).exec();
}
```

The logic works but my concern is if the favorites or comments step fails, the article won't be deleted and the database would lose its consistency.

Is there any way to call these 3 delete actions currently and execute all of them at once? And if is there an error, all of them should be canceled.

Comment: which package you are using to connect with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

```
    const session = await this.articleModel.collection.conn.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        //delete comments
        await this.commentModel.deleteMany({articleId});
        //delete favorites
        await this.favoriteModel.deleteMany({articleId});
        //delete article
        await this.articleModel.deleteOne({"_id": articleId});

        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
        // If an error occurred, abort the whole transaction and
        // undo any changes that might have happened
        await session.abortTransaction();
        throw new HttpException('Error deleting article', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } finally {
        session.endSession();
    }
```